how do I set an initial folder for a file-open dialog?
I'd like to have a button in my application which allows the user to open a file from within the application's special documents directory. I thought I could use the initial-folder property to set this, but I couldn't find a way to use it that did what I wanted. Here's a minimal example that doesn't do what I expect:
import Control.Concurrent
import GI.Gtk
import GI.Gio hiding (Application)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    app <- new Application []
    onApplicationActivate app $ do
        dlg <- new FileDialog [fileDialogInitialFolder :=> fileNewForPath "/"]
        fileDialogOpen dlg (Nothing :: Maybe Window) (Nothing :: Maybe Cancellable) Nothing
    applicationRun app Nothing
    threadDelay 3000000

(The threadDelay at the end is just to keep the application running long enough to see the dialog; there's no actual multithreading going on here beyond what gtk itself is doing.)
I expected this to open a dialog starting in the / directory; but instead it starts in /home/<my-username>. I can verify that fileNewForPath does actually create a File object with the correct path embedded: using various choices other than /, a retrieval and subsequent printing of the path does match the argument I send. But the dialog does not change where it begins.
What am I doing wrong? How should I instruct the dialog where to start?
To make this example complete and self-contained, here's a minimal cabal file you can use to build this:
cabal-version:      3.0
name:               test
version:            0.1.0.0
executable test
    main-is:          Main.hs
    build-depends:    base ^>=4.17.2.0, gi-gtk ^>=4.0, gi-gio ^>=2.0

Here's a C version that has essentially the same behavior (up to an additional blank window -- not sure why this was needed in the C version but the dialog doesn't seem to appear without it).
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer _unused) {
  GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  GtkFileDialog *dlg = gtk_file_dialog_new();
  GFile *fnm = g_file_new_for_path("/");
  gtk_file_dialog_set_initial_folder(dlg, fnm);
  gtk_file_dialog_open(dlg, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("x.x", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
  g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);
  return 0;
}

To compile and run:
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk4) -o test test.c $(pkg-config --libs gtk4)
./test


I've now played around with GtkFileDialog a bit more, and looked through its source. It seems too immature to be reasonably used yet; for example, there doesn't appear to be a way to observe when the user clicks "cancel". I intend to switch to GtkFileChooserNative instead; that appears to be what this file dialog stuff is wrapping anyway. So while this isn't really an answer, it is a way forward, in case anybody else ever runs across this.

The above C example sets initial dir in my env. In your env it sets path relatively to homedir, or fails completely? What shows g_print(">>> gtk-%d.%d.%d\n", gtk_get_major_version(), gtk_get_minor_version(), gtk_get_micro_version()); and g_print(">>> %s:%d: initial folder: %s\n", __func__, __LINE__, g_file_get_path(gtk_file_dialog_get_initial_folder(dlg))); for example?

@yvs2014 Setting other paths than "/" does exactly the same as setting "/": the dialog begins in my home directory regardless of where I start the program from or what path I ask for. This is gtk-4.10.5, and your other suggested line prints >>> activate:10: initial folder: /. (10, not 9, because I put both of your print statements there.)

It works with 4.10.5 runtime too in my env. Maybe it may shed some light:  following this https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/84 it's up to the used portal implementation and suggested to run with GDK_DEBUG=no-portals

Since I only work with C, I can only answer in that language.
The following line of code worked for me:
GtkFileDialog *dlg = gtk_file_dialog_new();
//  GFile *fnm = g_file_new_for_path(NULL);
  GFile *fnm = g_file_new_build_filename("/",NULL);
  gtk_file_dialog_set_initial_folder(dlg, fnm);

The problem is that g_file_new_for_path requires a glib encoded name.
So it also works like this:
  GtkFileDialog *dlg = gtk_file_dialog_new();
  const char *utf8Filename = "/";
  gchar *glibEncodedFilename = g_filename_from_utf8(utf8Filename, -1, NULL,NULL,NULL);
  GFile *fnm = g_file_new_for_path(glibEncodedFilename);
  gtk_file_dialog_set_initial_folder(dlg, fnm);
  gtk_file_dialog_open(dlg, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

Best regards
